# not able to see osgi deployment definition option (i.e to create .dpp file) in new wizard Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, osgi, kura

I am working on one of the POC for IoT project. To host Eclipse application on cloud service I need to create .dpp file i.e using the option
 New->Others->OSGI->Deployment definition package. But I am not able to see that option in Eclipse. How to get the Option to create dpp file?

Comment: Are you following a tutorial? Please provide a link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to install the Mtookit package into your Eclipse IDE. Instructions can be found here: http://eclipse.github.io/kura/dev/kura-setup.html